# How to return an integer in a %u string?

Tags: python, string, unicode, integer

I'm implementing code in Python, but I had to use previously implemented code. I am having trouble when using the inherited code, to show an integer in their HTML.

```
out.append(
   """<td align="right">%u us</td><td align="right">%u us</td><td align="right">%u us</td><td align="right"><a style="cursor:default" title="average block size: %u B">%u</a></td><td align="right"><a style="cursor:default" title="average block size: %u B">%u</a></td><td align="right">%u</td>"""
   % (rtime,wtime,fsynctime,rbsize,rops,wbsize,wops,fsyncops,)
)
```

This code is giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../disks_tab.py", line 652, in disks
fsyncops,
TypeError: %u format: a number is required, not str
```

I tried forcing the var type like this:

```
if fsyncops == "-":
   fsyncops = 0
```

Right above the out.append... code. The string "-" is what the variable is actually storing.

It is still not working and I get the same error.

Comment: `fsyncops` is being printed with `%d` format, not `%u`.

Comment: So one of the other variables is causing this error, although `%d` also requires a number.

Comment: What does `print((rtime,wtime,fsynctime,rbsize,rops,wbsize,wops,fsyncops))` show?

Comment: @Barmar you're right, the variable was %d because I was trying to fix it, the original is %u. I already fixed it. Those variables are meant to be shown in a table, as statistics of read and write options on a file in a HDD. They can be a value or "-". As I mentioned, this is not my code, I'm just trying to fix it, trying not to modify so much the original HTML code.

Comment: Please don't do that. We're want to help you, but it's difficult if the error message references a different version of the code.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the suggestion. I'll be more careful in the future.

Comment: There is no need to debug this for 8 variables at once in a convoluted HTML template. Please try and break this down into simply formatting an *individual* variable – most likely this will already show you which one is actually broken. You may want to take a look at the [mcve] help page – it is not only to help us help you, but to guide you to help yourself as well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, as you can see in the Traceback output, the variable with the error, is exactly "fsyncops" and I debugged it one by one until I realized it was actually this one

Comment: For complex format strings, the error will *not* point at the value which is incorrect but merely one of the values. Neither the shown line number nor the shown variable name mean that it was *exactly that* variable – any of the tuple may have failed. We cannot debug *which* variable is incorrect, you either have to do that yourself or provide a [mcve]. Iff the problem were with ``fsyncops``, then @Ictus' answer should have solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd try to cast the variable to the expected type (int in your case). This way you don't need to mess with your legacy code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

fsyncops = "-"

try:
  fsyncops = int(fsyncops)
except:
  fsyncops = 0

print ( """%u""" % (fsyncops,) )
```

Comment: @Ictus I already tried this, and it is not working either....

Comment: @Ictus I finally managed to solve it, using your approach, thank you very much. I didn't had to modify the inherited HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `%` operator to the `format()` method, and use `{}` placeholders. This doesn't require the corresponding parameter to be a specific type, it will use its `__str__` operator to format it.

```
out.append(
   """<td align="right">{} us</td><td align="right">{} us</td><td align="right">{} us</td><td align="right"><a style="cursor:default" title="average block size: {} B">{}</a></td><td align="right"><a style="cursor:default" title="average block size: {} B">{}</a></td><td align="right">{}</td>""".format(
    rtime,wtime,fsynctime,rbsize,rops,wbsize,wops,fsyncops)
```

Or change all the `%u` operators to `%s`.

Comment: Using ``.format`` isn't strictly necessary. The equivalent format placeholder to ``{}`` for the ``%`` operator is ``%s``.